# How to Increase Mobility Score to 55 in Quantitative Algorithms - Contributions?

Tags: algorithm, requirements

I'm currently working on a project involving Quantitative Algorithms, and my goal is to increase the mobility score to 55. I'm looking for guidance, insights, and practical strategies to help me reach this target. If you have experience or expertise in this area, please share your recommendations and suggestions on how to achieve a mobility score of 55 effectively. Your assistance is highly valued

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQVm.png)